# unsigned function inside generic object

Tags: javascript

I ran this on my console today for curiosity

```
var x={function(){return 2}};
```

It works. But why? How that nameless function is called? I don't see a point for this syntax to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here [object initializer](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) will interpret `x` as an object with key `function` which holds a [function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function).

`Firefox` and `Chrome` will interpret this statement (in different ways based on which ECMAScript version it is supporting); `IE11` will not interpret this statement.

Maybe the below code clarifies it more:

```js
window.onload = function() {

  // Is an object with key "function" which holds a 'function' object
  var x = {
    function() {
      return 2
    }
  };
  console.log(x);

  // Call the function
  console.log(x.function());

  // unwrap it for better clarity
  var y = function() {
    return 2
  };
  console.log(y);
  var z = {
    y
  };
  console.log(z);
  console.log(z.y());
}
```

Let's see another case:

```js
var x = {
  y() {
    return 2
  }
};
console.log(x);
console.log(x.y());
```

Short answer: Though the browser can interpret the statement, `function` is a bad key name for an object.

Answer (score 0):

This is an object literal with [shorthand method definition](https://rainsoft.io/6-ways-to-declare-javascript-functions/#3shorthandmethoddefinition) of `function`:

```
var x = {
  function(){
   return 2
  }
};
x.function() // => 2
```

To name the method `function` does not make much sense, but it's a valid JavaScript.

Comment: This is right, don't understand the downvote! typeof x will give you object and typeof x.function() will give you number (which is 2)

Comment: @aliasav Exactly. Downvoter doesn't know JavaScript :)

Comment: Right answer. But -1 for comment `Downvoter doesn't know JavaScript`.

Answer (score 0):

It's shorthand method names(ES6): https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer

```
var o = {
  property([parameters]) {},
};
```